# Sort RDD according to an Array() content

Tags: arrays, sorting, apache-spark, rdd

I have RDD[(Int , Array[Double])]
eg:

```
1, Array(2.0,5.0,6.3)
5, Array(1.0,3.3,9.5)
1, Array(5.0,4.2,3.1)
2, Array(9.6,6.3,2.3)
1, Array(8.5,2.5,1.2)
5, Array(6.0,2.4,7.8)
2, Array(7.8,9.1,4.2)
```

I have to collect the distinct value of the 1st column and arrange the whole RDD according to that array.

```
val label_array = rdd.map(_._1).collect.distinct
```

Output: Array(1,5,2) and now I have to arrange data according to label_array.

Required Output

```
1, Array(2.0,5.0,6.3)
1, Array(5.0,4.2,3.1)
1, Array(8.5,2.5,1.2)
5, Array(1.0,3.3,9.5)
5, Array(6.0,2.4,7.8)
2, Array(9.6,6.3,2.3)
2, Array(7.8,9.1,4.2)
```

I have tried

```
val ordering = (1,5,2).productIterator.toList.zipWithIndex.toMap
rdd.sortBy{case (k,v) => ordering(k)}
```

But how to get the required output as the Array will be varying(elements and size difference). How can I sort RDD according to array format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `zipWithIndex` your `label_array` and you should be fine

```
val ordering = label_array.zipWithIndex.map(x => (x._1, x._2)).toMap
```

And you should have your `ordering` map

```
scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 0, 5 -> 1, 2 -> 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

More easier way is to create a new RDD with distinct 1st column and join with the previous original column

Below is the simple example

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
        (1, Array(2.0,5.0,6.3)),
        (5, Array(1.0,3.3,9.5)),
        (1, Array(5.0,4.2,3.1)),
        (2, Array(9.6,6.3,2.3)),
        (1, Array(8.5,2.5,1.2)),
        (5, Array(6.0,2.4,7.8)),
        (2, Array(7.8,9.1,4.2))
      )
    )

    val distinct = rdd.map(v => (v._1, 1))distinct()
    //(v._1, 1)this is done because you need key value to join  

    //now join distinct with previous original RDD
    distinct.join(rdd).map(v => (v._1, v._2._2))
```

Output:

```
1, Array(2.0,5.0,6.3)
1, Array(5.0,4.2,3.1)
1, Array(8.5,2.5,1.2)
5, Array(1.0,3.3,9.5)
5, Array(6.0,2.4,7.8)
2, Array(9.6,6.3,2.3)
2, Array(7.8,9.1,4.2)
```